# How to call Winform method from Windows service in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services

I want to call Winform method from Windows Service.

For Example,
Here is my Winform application code (MyWinForm),

```
public void TestMethod(){
     MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");
}
```

And here is my Windows Service (MyService),

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args){
     MyWinform myWinform = new MyWinform();
     myWinform.TestMethod();
}
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: If the purpose is to show some UI (like in your example), then this is not possible as Windows Service is a non-ui background task.

Comment: Yeah I agree with your point but Winform supports ui right... And thank you so much for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

You can access winform methods from windows service by using name space **System.Windows.Forms**
How ever as hayden said *you can not access UI from windows servcie application*